# Programmatic injection with content script - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So i'm working on a plugin that has multiple different scripts that can be executed at all times, the only problem is the fact that the google API doesn't allow me acces to the full    **chrome.*** api through content scripts.

Here are some examples that I tried, but none of them seem to work.
Note: The newly injected scripts must be able to talk back and forth with the background-scripts.

**Content script:**

```
// This gives an error, since the chrome.* isn't allowed in content scripts:
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "script.js"});


// This doesn't allow me to talk back to the content scripts:
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}

// HTML 5 workers try to download the scripts from the web server, so that doesn't work either.
var worker = new Worker('script.js');
worker.postMessage();
```

Is there any way of injecting content scripts through other content scrips with javascript, and allowing the new scripts to talk back and forth with the background scripts?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to do?  Why can't the background script do all of the injecting?

Comment: Content-scripts cannot inject content-scripts (they can inject regular scripts only). The background page can inject content-scripts. Content-scripts can talk to the background page and vice versa. If your content-scripts feel lonely and need more content-scripts, they can send a message to the background-page, kindly asking it to inject their buddies (aka more content-scripts).